# Delete Multiple Images in GridView android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-gridview

I am building an app for practice purpose , so it goes like this that Images will be shown on screen in a gridView and :-

Below is the Screenshot of the app (done till now):-

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8re7R.jpg)

-if user clicks on an image another activity opens which shows the image that was clicked in fullscreen. (**done** this part)

-if user long presses an image , the Image is selected and user can select multiple Images.  (**done** this part)

-There is a menu on the Screen containing Delete icon/item and Set as Wallpaper icon/item. (**done** this part)

If User clicks on the delete icon of menu ,all the selected images should be deleted (**NOT DONE  , I am stuck in this part** ).

^ As you can see in this Image , i have selected two Images now if i click on the RecycleBin icon on menu , it only deletes ONE Image the starting one (pink color) i.e I am trying to delete the Images in Main Activity (In this case it's name is ImagesShow) and then calling notifyDataSetChanged within the loop or outside the loop but it only runs one time and deletes one image altough in for loop it detects that at the moment Number of Images Selected = 2. Below is a snippet of code for this part specifically , if someone need more detailed code in order to answer then i can also provide it.

```
//In MainActivity 
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId())

    {

        case R.id.deleteImages:

        //Inside RecycleBin Click
        //CountSelectedImages simply counts the Number of Images currently Selected
            if (CountSelectedImages() > 0)
            {
              //Images_List is an ArrayList of type Images where Images is an class containing ImagePath as well as boolean condition of IsSelected
                for (int x = 0,i=0; x < Images_list.size(); x++) 
                {

                            if (Images_list.get(x).IsSelected())
                            {
                              //In our above example , we should arive in this location 2 times.

                                Images_list.remove(x);

                              //I even tried to write NotifyDataSetChanged here in this if condition just after Removing the Images_List. 
                              //But it still runs one time only , only deleting the first Image that is Selected and never coming back inside this if condition.
                                ab.setSubtitle(CountSelectedImages() + "/" + Images_list.size() + " items Selected");

                            }

                  }

                    //So i read somewhere that we need to call notifyDataSetChanged once we have done all the changes in the array, so here is my final attempt but still it only runs for one time deleting only single image.
                            ((CustomImageAdapter) gridView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); //Can also write BaseAdapter instead of CustomImageAdapter
                             ClearWholeSelection(); //This functions clears the Selection of all Images , just as it happens in normal gallery
            }//end of if
    }//end of switch
}
```

However There is one glitch in this , i think if i try to catch it i might solve the problem.

Take this example:- 
GridView Currently contains following Views:-

### 0 1

### 2 3

### 4 5

**Now if i select ImageView 0 and 1 and press delete , it deletes only 0.
BUT if i press 0 , 2 and 4 , IT DELETES 0 , 2 and 4  ( Magic ? ) i.e IT WORKS FINE IN THIS CASE and also if i try to delete 1 , 3 , 5 
It 's somehow able to multiple delete images in a column but when it comes to row wise deletion it only deletes one image.**

Other Method i tried was to make a function of Remove(Image) in CustomImageAdapter, and in the above for loop just call , Remove (Images_List.get(x)). 
and in Remove(Image) i try to remove the Image in CustomImageAdapter List (same as Images_List) and then call NotifyDataSetChanged from the CustomImageAdapter.

Annnnnnd it also didn't worked.

If someone can solve this problem or explain the working of NotifyDataSetChanged in baseAdapter then please write your answer , need to clear my concept.

And there is also one interesting thing , i read in stackoverflow that getview() is called in a loop depending upon the getCount () function that you override , But then it totally blows my mind when i write in my Main Activity

```
Images_List.get(x).ToggleSelection();

((BaseAdapter)gridView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Annd it somehow runs the getView successfully and shows the "Selected" text on an image as you can see in the Screenshot Above , but the thing is that the count i.e Images_list.size() remains the same so why did the notifyDataSetChanged runs Successfully here??

P.S Sorry for Long Post :)

EDIT-------------SOLVED

Problem in this case is a Logical Error as i am iterating through the Images_List Array while also removing from it. 
Thanks to Ben's Answer (using Iterator) , my code works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are looping through your list as you remove from it. I'm surprised you're not getting a concurrent modification exception. At any rate, if you want to fix this I would recommend using iterator.

```
Iterator<Object> i = Images_List.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
   Object o = i.next();
    if( o.IsSelected() )
    {
      i.remove();
    }
}
```

Replace `Object` with the type of your list it's not included in the code you posted.

Comment: +1 Thanks , It's Working !!. And sorry i thought i had written all the necessary Information. Object type in my case was Images i.e a custom class and contains ImagePath and a boolean IsSelected.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can't comment so giving as answer itself
`Images_list.get(x).IsSelected()` what is Images_list in this, a list of bitmap object or a list of objects which inside contains bitmap and isSelected boolean?

And I don't think array will be better because in your case you will need to modify the list a lot which is hard if using array.

```
case R.id.deleteImages:
    List<int> indices = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Image image:Image_list){
        if(image.isSelected()){
            indices.add(Image_list.indexOf(image));
        {
    }
    //Now delete it from list
    for(int i:indices){
        Image_list.remove(i);
    }
                        ((CustomImageAdapter) gridView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); //Can also write BaseAdapter instead of CustomImageAdapter
                         ClearWholeSelection(); //This functions clears the Selection of all Images , just as it happens in normal gallery
        }//end of if
break;
}//end of switch
```

Comment: Images_List is an ArrayList<Images>. where Images is my custom class that contains two variables , Image Path as i am getting Images from Assets folder and 2nd variable which is boolean IsSelected

Comment: I agree with ben that you should not do two things concurrently on the list which is iterating it in for loop and removing it.

Comment: But you can save the index value and remove it later after for loop. Don't call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` inside for loop anywhere. it will refresh the screen in every iteration which is not good.

Comment: yeah that might also work. Can i do this that i keep my current code , and just store indexes of Selected Images and then call ((BaseAdapter)gridView.getAdapter()).removeImages(List_Indexes); and in that function after removing the Images using the Ben's answer and in the end writing notifyDataSetChanged(); ... Which Approach looks better ? altough both of these should work.

Comment: Yes if you have indexes stored seperatly that will work. Updated the answer for more clarification. Let me know for any problem.